# Assets 2.1 Pixel&Tonic

Tags: assets

****updated*** The issue was not having www in the url. Assets works fine if I use www.mysite.com/system.... but not if I use mysite.com/system... in the url. www is required in the url for Assets to work. Is this a htaccess issue or can u recommend a fix P&T please? Thanks*****

Just installed Assets 2.1 to test it out on EE2.5.5 - ran the ee server wizard and have what I need installed. If I try and update indexes in Assets the red button just turns opaque and does nothing. I also get no thumbnails and the refresh button just kept spinning endlessly. I reinstalled and uploaded Assets 2.1 twice. Seems to conflict with another module perhaps. Cache is 777, synchronised images in file pref etc...
Any ideas?
Thanks

update index does nothing (don't know where assets_test[2] is coming from? I have 2 images folders test and home...paths are correct)
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c1608dd
folder and thumbs not displayed
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=e7c53be

Comment: Just for future reference if you do find the answer to your own question then you can still right it up as an actual answer and accept it (after 2 days). This allows others to quickly find the solution and also reflects better on the stats of the forum. Maybe either accept Lisa's answer or right up your own with your Update.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what was happening, based on your update, is that you were seeing JS cross-site security blocking, due the lack of 'www'.   Your domains need to be consistent to avoid that problem - not just with P&T add-ons, at that.  You should ensure that your installation always uses either www, or no www. Consistency there should help you avoid running into this.

-Lisa Wess
Pixel & Tonic